# Non-blocking ReadConsoleInput

Tags: c, windows, winapi, console, mouse

I'm writing a Win32 console application that interacts with the mouse. I'm using `ReadConsoleInput` to get the window-relative mouse movements like so. Here's a simplified version of my problem:

```
int main(void)
{
    HANDLE hStdin;
    DWORD cNumRead;
    INPUT_RECORD irInBuf[128];
    hStdin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);

    SetConsoleMode(hStdin, ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT | ENABLE_MOUSE_INPUT | ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT);

    while (1)
    {
        mouse_position_changed = 0;
        ReadConsoleInput(hStdin, irInBuf, 128, &cNumRead);

        /* input handler here: changes the cursor position if the mouse position changed;
             clears screen if mouse position changed;
             sets mouse_position_changed (self-explanatory).
             (this part of the code is irrelevant to the quesiton at hand) */

        if (!mouse_position_changed)
            putchar('0');
    }
}
```

<sup>(I've removed most of the code including error checks. This is a simple, watered-down version of what I'm doing; it's much larger-scale than making 0's run away from the cursor.)</sup>

I want the screen to be cleared and the cursor set to the mouse coordinates whenever the mouse is moved. This part is **working**.

I want `0` to be printed the screen whenever the mouse is *not* moved. This will have the effect of 0's running away from the mouse cursor. This is **not working**, because [`ReadConsoleInput`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleinput) will block until it receives input.

The `0` is not printed until more input is received. Unless the user continually hits the keyboard, nothing is printed because whenever the mouse is moved, the screen is cleared.

### The problem

I would like the loop to continue even when no input is present. `ReadConsoleInput` waits for input to be read, which means that the loop will pause until the keyboard is hit, or the mouse is moved.

I'm looking for an alternative to `ReadConsoleInput`, or a way to make it non-blocking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is all documented in [ReadConsoleInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleinput). You can determine if there is a console input with [GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getnumberofconsoleinputevents). And you are able to to determine the type of console input events with [PeekConsoleInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/peekconsoleinput).

So [GetNumberOfConsoleInputEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getnumberofconsoleinputevents) is all you need.

You can also use [WaitForSingleObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms687032) with the console handle to wait for a next available input. This is also documented in [ReadConsoleInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleinput)

Comment: Just only to highlight the issue, be careful with the `WaitForSignleObject` or any other function like `ReadConsole` with internal blocking logic. You should not even call to these functions because basically you should pipe the data to the output handle, which means the handle might already closed/broken/detached while you being blocked on the input. You must always test the output even if no data on input. The `WaitForSingleObject` or `ReadConsole` can not deal with that by design. And that is a known design flaw in the Window console.